# Wpf: Can Trigger.Value refer to static property?

Tags: wpf

Basically I am trying to do this:

```
                <Trigger Property="Item" Value="{c:CollectionView.NewItemPlaceHolder}">
```

But the syntax is wrong. **Is this possible to do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Trigger Property="Item" Value="{x:Static c:CollectionView.NewItemPlaceHolder}">
```